# Magento Shopping Cart Price rule condition not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shopping-cart-price-rules, backend, promotions

I have added this condition for my shopping cart price rule Diagnostic center is a custom attribute. I think the condition is not working that's why coupon code is not applied. please help me in this work.Please help me in this for getting out of my problem.
[image: [][1][1]]

I need to solve it as soon as posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `contains` to `is` or `is one of`.

Comment: I have set it to is one of but it is showing coupon code is not valid.

Comment: please share the screen-shot or values of the field for the rule. May be some  condition is not correct.